# Custom OpenNLP Name Finder recognizes data in training set, but not in testing set

Tags: java, machine-learning, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

So I finally got OpenNLP incorporated into my project, and I have successfully trained my model on 15k lines of training data, stored it, and can load it when I want to use it to recognize entities in my program!

I am using it to recognize hashtags, so my training data looks something like this:

```
    ...
    Jim , I know you to be a fighter <START:HASHTAG> #usmarine <END> @ USMC Kira has your strength & amp ; ours @ t1r1u1t1h R love 2 U , Kira & amp ; 
    What has changed that people from your JAMAT are insulting Hindu GODS and GODDESSES . Calling our Religion names ... . 
    Ibtihaj represented the United States of America at the Olympics and brought home a medal , elevating the status of 
    A story point is a metric used in agile project management and development to determine ( or estimate ) the difficul 
    I 'm not shy or quiet , I just do n't find your mind appealing in any way shape or form and I 'm not gon na force a conv 
    <START:HASHTAG> #paradisepapers <END> , Canadian Taxpayers Federation ( CTF ) & amp ; tax reform `` CTF has not uttered even a single shocked-and-a 
    ...
```

I am finding that the model is unable to recognize any hashtags if it is passed a sentence that is not directly in my training set, such as:

```
String paragraph = "Take a shot for #harambe he took one for you!";
```

It will be unable to recognize the hashtag in this example, even though I checked and there is one instance of #harambe being used within my training data.

However, if I pass it a sentence directly from the training data:

```
String nameParagraph = "Idk whats funnier the #harambe or the fact that Im the only one who will see my page https : t.co/2eWjm6mOon ";
```

It will be able to recognize #harambe by properly identifying it as a HASHTAG.

I want my model to recognize all hashtags, hence I don't just want to feed it more instances of the #harambe hashtag so that it can recognize that SINGLE hashtag.

Any advice for how I can make my model properly identify new entities that are not within the training set? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use a regular expression to identify the hash tags?

Comment: So I was just using this as kind of a "first-test" to see if it could pick up something simple, I plan on using it for recognizing different kinds of entities that regex couldn't find as easily.

Comment: You might could make a custom feature generator to trigger on each "#" but I don't know how that would work out in use. Regardless, since a hashtag follows a pattern I'd stick with the regex if you can.

Comment: @KeatonMacLeod, if you are planning to train more NER models you could checkout [this project](https://gitlab.com/schrieveslaach/NLPf). It makes the annotation process more user friendly and it also could train and evaluate different NLP pipelines for you. Let me know if you want to give it a try. I'm happy to demonstrate the framework to you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to statistically model a problem that is deterministic.  jbird7 mentioned using regex, you could also:

Tokenize your text using a WhitespaceTokenizer

Iterate through the array of strings looking at the first character of the string (is it #).

```
\\ create a Tokenizer
Tokenizer tokenizer=WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE
String[] tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

\\ use old-style loop for span creation
List<Span> spans = new ArrayList<Span>()
for (int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
   if (token.charAt(0) == '#') spans.add(new Span(i,i+1,"HashTag"))
}
Span[] foundTags = spans.toArray(new Span[spans.size])
```

At this point, you should have the exact same output as your HashTagNameFinder.  Sorry if there are syntax errors.  The code should give you an idea of what you want to do.

Comment: Yes you're right. as jbird7 mentioned above, regex would work perfectly. I should have indicated that I was using the hashtags just as a "first-test" to see if the model could recognize a simple entity. I plan on using it to recognize some other entities that regex couldn't identify eg.) activities -> hiking, drawing, soccer. However thanks for the advice regarding the regex, I will turn to that concept to recognize entities that are deterministic.

Comment: Ok, then the reason that your trained model did not find the #harambe is probably because you don't have enough training data yet.  The classifier uses features such as the word, the two words previous, whether the word and two words previous are capitalized.  So it takes more than a few examples to train the classifier.  For the example you gave, add a feature that checks if the first letter of the current word is a hashtag.  That feature is so strong, you should be able to make a decent classifier with just  few examples.

Comment: To create custom features see https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.featuregen

Comment: This definitely seems like something that would help create a better model! I was looking through the documentation, but didn't find a concrete example of how I would go about implementing a custom feature that would tell the model, "This one has a hashtag, that's a strong feature, remember that!" ! Do you know where there is a small code example that shows how to implement your own feature as you have mentioned above, as that would be the answer to the initial question asked, and I could close out the thread! Thanks for your help, as I didn't even know about custom feature generation!